# Error in C# Code Backup option

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have wrote this code 
but its generating error

please help

```
System.IO.File.Copy("JDB.mdf", "d:\\JDB.mdf", true);
System.IO.File.Copy("JDb_log.ldf", "d:\\JDb_log.ldf", true);
```

the error is

> The process cannot access the file 'JDB.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

Please help me

Comment: Are you sure that you're not in using JDB.mdf ?

Comment: You can't do a straight file copy of a live database file (ie one with a running database using it), it will most likely not be consistent and you'd be restoring a corrupt database.

Comment: See [how to use C# and SMO to create backups of your SQL Server databases](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using)

Answer (score 3):

1. The file is being used by some process. I believe the database is still attached to Sql Server.
2. Use Process Explorer tool from Sys Internal to find out the program using this file.
3. Why don't you use SQL back tool to backup the database?

Check out [What happens during a live SQL Server backup?](https://serverfault.com/questions/100490/what-happens-during-a-live-sql-server-backup)

If you still want to backup or make copy of ldf mdf files then you can perform these steps:
1. Detach database

```
USE MASTER;
GO
-- Take database in single user mode -- if you are facing errors
-- This may terminate your active transactions for database
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
-- Detach DB
EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'DatabaseName'
```

2. Open Windows Explorer go to the the folder where ldf and mdf files are and then copy the file manually.
3. Reattach the database:

> ```
> USE [master]
>     GO
>     CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseName] ON
>     ( FILENAME = N’C:\Data\DataBase_Data.mdf’ ),
>     ( FILENAME = N’C:\Data\Database_Log.ldf’ )
>     FOR ATTACH
>     GO
>     IF EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases sd  
>     WHERE name = N’DataBaseName’ AND SUSER_SNAME(sd.owner_sid) = SUSER_SNAME() )
>         EXEC [AdventureWorks].dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame=N’sa’,@map=false
> ```

4. If you want to do it programatically, then you can execute the command given in step 1,2,3 using ADO.NET and the use c# file copy command to copy the file.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and run the program.

**Option 1:**

Click the Find menu, and choose Find Handle or DLL...

Type the file name (in your case JDB.mdf)

After typing the search phrase, click the Search button

Once you know what process the file has locked you, need to close that process (by closing that program). Another option is to use KILL in the process explorer terminating that process.

**Option 2:**

From the error message, the .mdf file has already been attached to an instance of an SQL Server. If you have multiple instances running, make sure it is detached from any other instance.

Comment: okey
everything is clear to me, now 
Please tell me how to take the backup of the MDF File Database.